# Return variables in real time through programs in c++

Tags: c++

I have a program written in c++. I'm looking for how I can catch its values in real time with another c++ program. 
For example I have in the program something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (true) {
        cout << n << endl;
        n++;
    }
}
```

That's simple but represents how my real program  works, which gives values to `n` every few milliseconds.
Now I want to catch the `n` values and store them in a new program at the same time it appears in the command windows.

Comment: ***how I can catch its values in real time with another program in c++*** It's probably better to communicate directly with the other application.

Comment: Debuggers are the programs which does this in general. Usually, in a modern OS, one process may not access data of another. With special permissions, there can be exceptions. Usually, if two processes want to share data, you need some kind of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). E.g. if your sample would store `n` in shared memory, another process could watch this data as well.

Comment: Concerning debuggers and their special permissions, I'm a bit uncertain and googled a bit and found e.g. this: [Debug Privilege](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-privilege). However, I still would clearly vote for IPC in your case. ;-)

Comment: not sure I fully understand , but it looks like you could pipe your application into your catcher i.e "program | catcher"

Comment: @newbie Simple idea but not bad. (I ignored the `cout << n << endl;` assuming this as "any kind of side effect".) However, the pity is the wrong order in this case: On the read end of pipe, it doesn't reflect the current state of `n` but the soon out-of-date one. Though, this could be solved by a simple re-ordering of statements. In so far, connecting std I/O channels by a pipe is just another kind of IPC (and mentioned in the above Wikipedia link). ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by real time? Most operating systems are not real time systems. Are you talking about embedded systems?

Comment: @Scheff  I'm really have no idea about IPC and less than pipes, can you explain it in more detail or redirect me to a tutorial or something?

Comment: @newbie the same question as above

Comment: @ThomasSablik it's a program that recognize an object through a camera and store the positions (x, y) in real time.

Comment: Concerning IPC, I provided the Wikipedia link which gives an overview. Among others, it lists files. This is nothing else than one process writes a file, where concurrently another reads it -> a simple interprocess communication. If one process writes to standard out and another reads from standard in, you can connect these programs on shell level (as recommended by @newbie) -> that's interprocess communication as well.

Comment: @Scheff you can explain with an example code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications Pipe examples cliking on "Pipes". Also, search the web for "IPC " and "pipes" tutorial.

Comment: If you are talking about a usb camera on a mac, linux or windows system you shouldn't use the term real time as it means something different. This operating systems usually don't support real time processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a very simple sample for two processes communicating over a pipe.

As it was my intention to demonstrate it on coliru, I had to put the code for both processes into one program. Whether the program acts as writer or reader is decided by commandline argument. Here, is the source code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

namespace Writer {

int main()
{
  // produce some values
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // consume some time e.g. for reading camera
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(50));
    // determine position
    const int x = std::rand(), y = std::rand();
    // write values to stream
    std::cout << i << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}

} // namespace Writer

namespace Reader {

int main()
{
  // consume some values
  for (int i = 0;; ++i) {
    // read values
    int iW, x, y;
    if (!(std::cin >> iW >> x >> y)) break;
    // report values
    std::cout << i << ": " << iW << ", x: " << x << ", y: " << y << '\n';
  }
  // report lost input
  std::cout << "End of input.\n";
  // done
  return 0;
}

} // namespace Reader

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const std::string arg1 = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "";
  if (arg1 != "-i" && arg1 != "-o") {
    std::cerr << "Usage:\n"
      << "a.out -o ... to start the writer\n"
      << "a.out -i ... to start the reader\n";
    return -1;
  }
  if (arg1 == "-o") return Writer::main();
  else return Reader::main();
}
```

Compiled and started with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out -o | ./a.out -i
```

Output:

```
0: 0, x: 1804289383, y: 846930886
1: 1, x: 1681692777, y: 1714636915
2: 2, x: 1957747793, y: 424238335
3: 3, x: 719885386, y: 1649760492
4: 4, x: 596516649, y: 1189641421
5: 5, x: 1025202362, y: 1350490027
6: 6, x: 783368690, y: 1102520059
7: 7, x: 2044897763, y: 1967513926
8: 8, x: 1365180540, y: 1540383426
9: 9, x: 304089172, y: 1303455736
End of input.
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e2070815615ef6c)</kbd>

This is how it works:

1. `main()` does nothing else than evaluating the command line argument and calling `Reader::main()` or `Writer::main()` (or printing an error if no proper argument could be found).
2. `Writer::main()` produces some values (with a delay of 50 ms to make it more exciting/realistic) and writes it to `std::cout`.
3. `Reader::main()` consumes some values which are read from `std::cin`.

That's it.

The actual magic is how it is called:

```
./a.out -o | ./a.out -i
```

I'm not sure what OS and shell is behind coliru but it looks like Linux. (It probably would work on a Windows 10 prompt as well but I'm not that familiar with this. I'm mostly using [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) for such cases as I'm a [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) fan.)

It starts `./a.out` (the default output of the C++ compiler) in two processes one with arg `-o` the other with arg `-i`. Thereby, the pipe symbol `|` connects the standard output channel of the former to the standard input channel of the latter. (The invention of pipes and this pipe syntax was one of the revolutionary Unix concepts. The inventors wanted to connect tools like garden hoses – I once read somewhere.)

To be fair, I must admit that it was [newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9131933/newbie) who mentioned this idea in his comment.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer and then if I want an IPC between a code write in c++ and octave for example, it could be similar?

Comment: @RafaHernández octave like [GNU Octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave)? Basically, you can pipe standard output of any application to standard input of any other application. It's an OS/shell feature i.e. language agnostic. Concerning octave, it might be necessary to use the command-line interface for this. (In GUI mode, the standard I/O channels are probably re-directed internally.) And btw. pipes are not limited to standard in/out but that's the most easy way to use them.